# Graph visualization library for Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to find a graph visualization library for Angular 2+ 
Maybe something similar to

http://angularjs-graph.org/

Found this one:
https://github.com/compodoc/ngd

Any other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Quite good question. I'd add that at the moment (Sep, 18) "ngd" cannot proceed big projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This great component could be the answer
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph

Comment: I don't think this is  right, given the context of OP's question.

ngx-graph is for drawing graphical data.
OP is asking for a tool like compodoc that generates dependeny-graph of an angular project.

Comment: Hi @vivekmore I am actually answering my own question :) which is in more general terms not specific to angular.

Comment: @doorman So you don't want a _dependency graph generator_, just a graphing tool? I'd update your question title, because I fell on this question looking for something that will compute what you asked for: a module dependency graph (as in the data structure, not the visual representation).

Comment: @msanford thanks for your suggestion, I just updated the title